# It is possible to set requirements for inputs GitHub actions?

Tags: github-actions

I want to make two inputs in the workflow, but I need to ensure that the second input becomes available only after the value I need is selected in the first input.

Is it possible to do this with GitHub actions?

Answer (score 0):

You can now specify input types for manually triggered workflows allowing you to provide a better experience to users of your workflow. In addition to the default string type, we now support choice, boolean, and environment.

Comment: Thank you. It's not exactly what I need. What is my logic. I want to run auto-tests manually via СI.
To do this, I add the first input in the workflow in which I can choose - regression, smoke, or run a test for a single API service.
I need the second input in order to run a single API service if this item is selected in the first input. If not selected, the second input is not displayed or must be disabled. It seems to me that there is no such thing in GitHub actions, but nevertheless, I decided to check with those in the know.